# Restrictor Nozzle Back Pressure

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure

Using a flow restriction to create backpressure.  The back pressure is very important as it is used to drive a piston.  What nozzle/flow restrictor shape will create the highest pressure drop/back pressure.

Comment: the highest upstream pressure will be from a variable restrictor which is fully closed (but you knew that)... what measure are you trying to maximize?

Comment: like a .1 mm hole.  tell us what you're trying to do.